# where to get flutter color code like (0xFFff4b4b)?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, hex

### where to get flutter color code

i wanna change background color using hexa color. But I can only pickup flutter defaults values

```
class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  var customFontWhite = GoogleFonts.coiny(
      textStyle:
          const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, letterSpacing: 3, fontSize: 28));
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Tic-Tac-Toy',
          style: customFontWhite,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: * see [this][1] 


  [1]: https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use `Color();`, don't forget to start always with `0xFF`

```
Color(0xFFYour color);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this:

```
backgroundColor: Color(0xFFff4b4b),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hexa colors without using any packages, just type

```
Color(0xffff4b4b)
```